# How can I present fields with similar name on mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection name 'persons'. Inside the collection, I have the following structure. I would like to get to present all the fields that contain the term "friend".

```
name: 'David',
contacts: {
  friend_1: 'Bill'
  friend_2: 'George'
  friend_3: 'Donald'
  friend_4: 'Richard'
  managaer: 'James'
  mentor: 'Andy'
}
```

I thought to try maybe `db.persons.find({}, {/.*friend.*/: 1})`, but obviously it didn't work.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, obviously this is not the best structure, but is what it is, and then you can use this aggregation query:

- First set the object as array with `$objectToArray` to filter by the regex.
- Then use `$filter` with `$regexMatch` to get only values you want into the array.
- And recreate the object again using `$arrayToObject`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "contacts": {
        "$objectToArray": "$contacts"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "name": 1,
      "contacts": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$contacts",
          "as": "c",
          "cond": {
            "$regexMatch": {
              "input": "$$c.k",
              "regex": ".*friend.*",
              "options": "i"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "contacts": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$contacts"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GmDyreHrn9Q)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be a correct structure. If this is the case, maybe you can store an array in 'friends' field.

```
name: 'David',
contacts: {
  friends: ['Bill', 'George', 'Donald', 'Richard'],
  manager: 'James',
  mentor: 'Andy'
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's not a good structure. Unfortunately, I can not change the structure.